# Kendogrid column filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

What is the best approach to implement:-

1. Filter column in kendogrid based on idcolumn(key) in datasource.

The id column is not visible in kendogrid however filter must be applied based on the value

Comment: What means "best approach"? Are you talking about how to implement it, how to display it,...?

Comment: I mean how to implement it

Comment: Here how to implement it relates how to present it. In the [dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/ifUXosIp) that you provided, you are actually filtering it but the question is how to change the filtering condition because the column is not visible. From my point of view there are two options: first is display the column but not the content; second, define a custom command that allows to enter the condition. Is any of this a potentially valid solution?

Comment: How would we display the column without the content?

Comment: Using a template. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is displaying the column but hiding the value. Not sure if this is very user-friendly (how will the user know which values to filter). If this is something doable for you, you can define a template for the `id` column that is empty.

Example based on your `dojo`.

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  data: [
    { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30, id: 1 },
    { name: "John Doe", age: 33, id: 2 }
  ],
  filter: [
    // omit all items, which id is equal to 1"
    { field: "id", operator: "eq", value: 1 }
  ]
});

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "name", filterable: { multi: true } },
    { field: "id", template: "" },
    { field: "age", filterable: { multi: true } }
  ],
  dataSource: ds,
  filterable: true
});
```

```js
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
     data: [
        { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30, id: 1 },
        { name: "John Doe", age: 33, id: 2}
      ],
    filter: [
    // omit all items, which id is lesser than 10"
    { field: "id", operator: "eq", value: 1 }
  ]
  });
  
 
   
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [
      { field: "id", template: "", filterable: { multi: true }, width: 50 },
      { field: "name",filterable:{ multi: true} },
      { field: "age" ,filterable:{ multi: true} }
    ],
    dataSource: ds,
    filterable: true
  
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="grid"></div>
```